# Java opening a new Jframe instantly so it appears without a delay

Tags: java, button, jframe

I am currently trying to open a new Jframe when a button is pressed and this is the easy part. But there is a slight delay opening the new Jframe.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;    
import javax.swing.JFrame;

 public class Aframe implements ActionListener {   

public void frame() {
JFrame frame = new JFrame("1");
    JButton button =new JButton("Start");  
    JButton button2 =new JButton("Help");  
    button.setBounds(50,100,110,30); 
    button2.setBounds(50,150,110,30); 
frame.setSize(890,700);
frame.setLocation(300,60);
    frame.setLayout(null);  //tillfälligt 
frame.setResizable(false);
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    frame.add(button);
    frame.add(button2);

    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){  
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){  
            frame.dispose();
            JFrame frame2 = new JFrame("2");
            frame2.setSize(890,700);
            frame2.setLocation(300,60);
            frame2.setVisible(true);
            frame.dispose();
            frame2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                }  
            });  

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    start.frame();
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    
}

}
```

I would like to have it appear instantly when the button is pressed or at least make it seem so. I guess it actually might be easier to repaint the entire frame rather than opening a new one? But I feel like asking here first.

Comment: @5f3bde39-70a2-4df1-afa2-47f61b Tried this already and it produces the same result as the code above

Comment: [Avoid null layouts in Swing](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/114-avoid-null-layouts-in-swing)
Also, you should really only have one `JFrame` per app. If you want extra windows, they would normally be dialog types, not application windows

Comment: @g00se The layout was there temporarily I just noticed I have forgotten to delete it but thanks for the reminder. And yes you think it is simply easier to just reload/repaint the original Jframe?

Comment: Well it looks like you've got a 'roving interface' so as @user16320675 said, a `CardLayout` might be the thing.

Comment: @user16320675 many thanks, will google around about how to use card layout.

Comment: Many thanks @g00se (I was unable to ping both in single comment)